# how to check if an object exists in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to check if the window.sessionStorage object exists. Is this the way to do it:

```
if (window.sessionStorage)
```

in javascript?

Comment: That's a way to check if the property isn't a falsy value, it could be any truthy value including objects.

Comment: Unless you really did want to check whether there were no items in `sessionStorage` (which is not common; you should probably check for specific keys instead), use what you have in the question and not what was written in the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(sessionStorage.length == 0) {
    //do something
}
```

That will validate whether `sessionStorage` is empty or not. Alternatively, you can use this:

```
if(typeof(sessionStorage) == 'undefined')  {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: The first check here could possibly fail, since if `sessionStorage` didn't exist on the global object, there would be an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Use can use [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) to check session/web storage and other browser features.

In case you can't add the lib, check how they handle it [here](https://gist.github.com/remy/350433)

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Your proposed solution will work since we know that the `sessionStorage` property must refer to an object—and objects always resolve truthy in expressions.

However a word of caution, when checking for the existence of any arbitrary property in JavaScript (where we don't necessarily know the value), it's safest to check that the key exists in the object of interest. For example:

```
var exists = (someObject && 'someProp' in someObject);
```

We need to do this because `someProp` could be a valid property yet the test would fail when equal to: `false`, `""`, `0`, or any other value that would be falsey in an expression.